# How to reshape a text file?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a file like this that I want to reshape and transform into columns:

```
   fe=read.table("foo.txt")
   > fe
            V1
  1         9
  2        Sd
  3          2
  4       Sd
  5          5
  6       Smn
  7          7
  8        Smn
  9          5
  10      bf
  11         4
  12      bf

 > str(fe)
 'data.frame':   12 obs. of  1 variable:
  $ V1: Factor
```

desired output:

```
 Sd 9 2
 Smn 5 7
 bf 5 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

```
# step 1: create new dataframe
fe2 <- data.frame(id = fe$V1[c(FALSE,TRUE)], 
                  num = as.numeric(as.character(fe$V1[c(TRUE,FALSE)])))

# step 2: reshape into the desired format
fe2$rid <- with(fe2, ave(as.character(id), id, FUN = seq_along))
reshape(fe2, idvar = "id", timevar = "rid", direction = "wide")
```

which returns a data.frame:

> ```
>    id num.1 num.2
> 1  Sd     9     2
> 3 Smn     5     7
> 5  bf     5     4
> ```

---

As an alternative for step 2, you could also use the `data.table`-package:

```
# step 2 (alternative): reshape into the desired format
library(data.table) # v1.9.8 or higher is required for the 'rowid'-function
dcast(setDT(fe2), id ~ rowid(id, prefix = 'num.'), value.var = 'num')
```

This will return a *data.table* (which is an enhanced *data.frame*) with the same structure as the base R solution.

Comment: What is the version of `data.table` do you have? This function is present from *v1.9.8* and above.

Comment: @bicton see the update with a complete base R solution; for the `data.table`-alternative for the 2nd step you might need to update the `data.table`-package to the latst version (currently *v1.10.4*)

Answer (score 2):

We reshape the column 'V1' by converting to a `matrix` and then to `data.frame`, then `unstack` and transpose to get the expected output

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(fe$V1, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE))
d1$V1 <- as.integer(as.character(d1$V1))
res <- t(unstack(d1, V1~V2))   
res
#    [,1] [,2]
#bf     5    4
#Sd     9    2
#Smn    5    7
```